# Embedding of curves in projective spaces... typo?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, projective-space

I'm reading from the book "[Geometry of algebraic curves](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387909974)", by Griffiths, Harris, Arbarello and Cornalba.

In the middle of page 5 they define the map $\phi_{\mathscr{D}}:C\to \mathbb{P}V^*$, from a curve $C$ to the projectified linear subspace $\mathbb{P}V$ of $H^0(C,L)$, by the prescription $\phi(p)=$"sections $s\in V$ which vanish at $p$".

It doesn't make sense to me! It should be defined, instead, as

$\phi(p)=$"sections $s\in V$ which **don't** vanish at $p$",

so that the target is really $\mathbb{P}V^*$, since the zero section doesn't belong to the image of any point.

Do you agree with me and this is a typo or am I losing something?

Here's part of the page:

[image: Geometry of algebraic curves - Page 5]

Comment: It is unlikely for anyone without the book at hand to be able to offer an answer to this question. You leave so many things undefined. Could you please explain all of the unknowns in this post? My hunch is that it is highly unlikely for there to be a mistake so early on in the book. Perhaps if you take the time to spell out all of the details in a revised post, you will find where the problem lies.

Comment: You can check the first pages of the book in the link I provided, by clicking on "Look inside"

Comment: I would suggest that instead of expecting people to go to an external site, sign-up to Amazon and then read the first five or six pages of a book, you might instead take the time to explain the background to your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess would be that $p\in C$ defines a linear functional on $V$ by the rule $p(s) = s(p).$ We see that it is linear since we of course have $p(s_1+s_2)=(s_1+s_2)(p)=s_1(p)+s_2(p)$ and similarly for scalar multiplication. Thus, the set $\{s\in V:s(p)=0\}$ is a hyperplane in $V$ cut out by the linear functional $p.$ That is, we map $p$ to the point in $\mathbb P(V^*)$ corresponding to the hyperplane.

Comment: Yes, and that is precisely why a base point causes trouble; all the sections vanish at such a point and so a base point can't be sent to a hyperplane!